# Install role services using command line

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, windows-server-2012

I am taking a Windows Server class and I am supposed to install/uninstall some role services using CLI and PowerShell.

Now it was easy to figure out using PowerShell since there are Install-WindowsFeature and Uninstall-WindowsFeature cmdlets.

But my lab assignment is asking me to provide commands for the CLI.

Is there a way to install/uninstall role services from the CLI?

Just to note: I am using Microsoft's MOAC Lab Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install-WindowsFeature –Name feature_name -ComputerName computer_name -Restart

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee344834.aspx according to this, it says it's no longer available on server 2012

Comment: is that different from ServerManagerCmd.exe

Comment: I just got the Server 2012 command line from TechNet myself.  Let me see if I can find the article again.

Comment: Okay, the article I read was for 2008.  CLI for 2012 is done at the PowerShell command prompt, not the DOS command prompt, so it's a little different but not much.

Comment: okay good to know. that clears up my confusion though. the lab assignment i am doing is asking for PowerShell examples AND CLI examples, but idk why..

Comment: Well, it's still CLI, but the PS CLI.  Perhaps by PS (not CLI) they mean scripted.